# Quick access to features by searching

Tags: ios

In iOS application, tab bar id added containing more than 10tabs and screens.
Note: Tab bar is just example.

I want to implement search menu(feature), so that user can search and quickly navigate to particular screen. There are number of screens and to go to particular screen user has to taps number of time. So here I have to provide search option so that user can search and quickly navigate to particular screen. I want to minimize number of taps and provide quick access to all features in the application.

For e.g) When user enter text 'edit profile', app should show options relevant to entered text like "Edit Profile". When user tap on it, it should navigate to Edit profile screen.

What should be approach to implement such kind of functionality?
Do I need to define all features somewhere? 
How to manage navigation? 
How to provide suggestions as per entered search text?

Comment: Use Hamburger and split into 4 tabs and remaining in the  Hamburger

Comment: @Spynet I already have tab bar added. But I think that doesn't matter, I have implement search feature for quick access.

Comment: Access the tabbar via their index selected index

Comment: self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3

Comment: What if navigation or tab bar index changes by reordering or visibility? I am looking for approach, which will fit in all cases with minimum changes.

Comment: your miss understood the tab-bar and navigation controller please be clear on it

Comment: You need to use core data to maintain matching string along with the index so now you search the "edit profile" .... "Edit Profile" -> self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = IndexOf(Edit Profile) // use predicate i just use sample data like that or else integrate this one https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=scrollable+tab

Comment: HI, did you got answer please post ...

Comment: @Spynet NO, I am looking for better approach..This kind of approach is already implemented which is creating problems as UI changes. Thanks.